# change url and reload after $location.search()

Tags: angularjs

Sounds simple but I'm kinda stuck here.

```
$scope.triggerFetch = function() {
       $location.search("zipcode", 344343); // this just replaces it but I need a reload as well
       // now do the GET request
}
```

I use angular just for the UI interactions, the rendering and the heavy lifting does the backend framework.

I can replace the url but I need a function for the reload, I don't want to use **$location.path()**, there must be something more elegant.

Comment: Is reloadOnSearch set to false in your route configuration? It should reload when you set it.

Comment: I didn't include ng-route, I want to keep the dependencies low, as I said, I just need angular for ui interactions. Do I have to include ng-route for that feature?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, my only interaction with that feature is using ngRoute. If it is changing the URL correctly, you could watch for changes on the scope and call `$window.location.reload()`

Comment: Yea, feel free to create an answer, I'll accept it then. I added ng-route to my dependendencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the comments)

You can either add `ngRoute` as a dependency which will cause a reload when the search parameters are changed.

Option 2 is to do something like the following:

```
$scope.$watchCollection($location.search(), function () {
    $window.location.reload();
})
```